# FastAPI + SqlAlchemy: Left join

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, left-join, fastapi

I am new to using both FastAPI and SqlAlchemy with PostgreSQL. I've been working on creating some models, which started out fine.

```
class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "parents"
  uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = "children"
  uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.uid"))
  parent = relationship("Parent", backpopulates="children")
```

This part works as I would expect, and I can create Parent and Child objects, with Child models having `parent_id` fields as ForeignKeys that reference the `Parent.uid` fields.
My issue is when I now try to obtain a parent and it's children in a query. For this I use the SqlAlchemy query function:

```
  session.query(Parent).outerjoin(Child).all()
```

In my mind this should give me a parent object that looks something like this:`{ uid: 1, children: [{ uid: 111 }] }`. However all I get is: `{ uid: 1 }`. While it does not throw an error, it doesn't show me the child data. When I look at the query used by SqlAlchemy (using `query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})`) I get:

```
SELECT parent.uid, child.uid as uid_1 FROM parents LEFT OUTER JOIN children ON parent.uid = child.parent_id;
```

Which is about what I would expect and when I run this in the psql shell I get the expected result:

```
 uid | uid_1
-----+-------
   1 |   111
```

I've tried various different ways to define the relationship, both in the joins and model declarations (backrefs, declaring explicit joins such as `.outerjoin(child, child.parent_id == parent.uid`, etc.), but nothing I do gives me the output I am looking for from the SqlAlchemy query. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: check this line -> `children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")` . Have you fix this `back_populates` with `parents` instead `parent`? because your table name is `parents`

Comment: @danangjoyoo I believe `back_populates` references columns, not the tables themselves. That seems to be how it is used here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the ORM usually you reference the relationships off the parent like this:

```
for parent in session.query(Parent).all():
    for child in parent.children:
        # do something here
        pass
```

This executes a query every time you have to fetch the children (when using lazy loading) for a parent which is not what you want.

There are lot of loading strategies to "load" the children.  One that emulates what you describes is a joined load, like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joined_load

q = session.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.children))
for parent in q.all():
    for child in parent.children:
        # these children should already be loaded
        pass
```

You would use a regular join like in your example if you needed to filter the parent based on a child column.

You can load different relationships different ways both dynamically like above and beforehand by setting the loading setting on the relationship itself. You can read about these things below:

- [loading_relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html)
- [joinedload](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload)